# xbmc hangs on video loading

Tags: applications, media-player, video-streaming

I've installed xbmc media center: http://xbmc.org/download

I added a video program ("The Daily Show") -- but I can't access the video files -- because it says "Working..." and nothing happens.

The same procedure works on PC.

I tried both current stable ("Frodo"), and beta ("Gotham") versions of xbmc app.

So my question is: how do I make it work?

**Edit**:

I'm on Samsung GT-S7562 Galaxy S Duos running Android 4.0.4 (KyleOPEN ROM v3.4.0).

Comment: It would help to know which device you're installing it on, and the version of Android OS it's running.

Comment: @Chahk see edit.

Comment: Could you please run the following command in Terminal Emulator (or ADB shell): `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and see if the "Features" line contains the words "vfp" and "neon"?

Comment: @Chahk I did it from terminal emulator in android. Yep - both "vfp" and "neon" are there.

Comment: This means the CPU is compatible with XBMC app. Rules out incompatibility issues. Next step is getting the logs while trying to launch the video.

Comment: @Chahk good idea. I'll try to research [logs](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Android_FAQ#Userdata_folder_and_logs).